# How do I end the while loop in my tic-tac-toe program?

Tags: ruby, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

I wrote a tic-tac-toe program which is user vs user. There is s while loop in the code which makes it run over and over for turns. However, this loop doesn't break when someone wins. Any suggestions?

Here is My code:

```
   class Game

        def initialize
                @board=Array.new
                @board[1]="__|"
                @board[2]="__"
                @board[3]="|__"
                @board[4]="\n__|"
                @board[5]="__"
                @board[6]="|__"
                @board[7]="\n  |"
                @board[8]="  "
                @board[9]="|  "
                @turn="x"
                @win_status = false
        end


        def win_status
                return @win_status
        end

        def show_board
                @board.each do |i|
                        print i
                end
        end

        def set_turn #switches turns
        if @turn == "x"
                @turn = "o"
        else @turn == "o"
                @turn = "x"
        end
        end

        def make_move
                puts "Enter x coordinate"
                x=gets.to_i
                puts "Enter y coordinate"
                y=gets.to_i
@board[1]="_"+@turn+"|"   if y==1 && x==1
@board[2]="_"+@turn    if y==2 && x==1
@board[3]="|_"+@turn   if y==3 && x==1
@board[4]="\n_"+@turn+"|" if y==1 && x==2
@board[5]="_"+@turn    if y==2 && x==2
@board[6]="|_"+@turn   if y==3 && x==2
@board[7]="\n "+@turn+"|" if y==1 && x==3
@board[8]=" "+@turn    if y==2 && x==3
@board[9]="|"+@turn+" \n"    if y==3 && x==3
        end
 def win_combo
@win_combo = [*[@board[1][1] + @board[2][1] + @board[3][2]], [@board[4][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[6][2]], [@board[7][1] + @board[8][1] + @board[9][1]],[@board[1][1] + @board[4][2] + @board[7][1]], [@board[2][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[8][1]], [@board[3][2] + @board[6][2] + @board[9][1]], [@board[1][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[9][1]], [@board[3][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[7][1]]]
        end

        def check_win
                #if some row or column or diagonal is "xxx" or "ooo" then set @win_status = true
                @win_combo.each do |str|
                        if str == "xxx" or str == "ooo"
                                @win_status = true

                        end
                end
                puts @win_status
        end
end


g = Game.new
while g.win_status != true
g.set_turn
g.make_move
g.show_board
g.win_combo
g.check_win
end
```

Comment: Do you get `true` when you `puts @win_status`?

Comment: Do you ever `check_win`?

Comment: When do you call `check_win` to know whether someone has won?

Comment: Did I forget to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check if you won (`check_win`) and you don't change `@win_combo`

```
while g.win_status != true
    #puts g.check_win
    g.set_turn
    g.make_move
    g.show_board
    g.win_combo #this line
    g.check_win #and this line
end
```

And in your @win_combo suppose to be **array of strings** not **array of arrays of strings**. 
For example, your old code:

```
[["ooo"], ["_xx"], ["   "], ["o_ "], ["ox "], ["ox "], ["ox "], ["ox "]]
```

new one:

```
["ooo", ["_x_"], ["   "], ["o_ "], ["ox "], ["o_ "], ["ox "], ["ox "]]
```

Just add `*` ad the beginning(as I did here) or just don't make arrays:

```
@win_combo = [*[@board[1][1] + @board[2][1] + @board[3][2]], [@board[4][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[6][2]], [@board[7][1] + @board[8][1] + @board[9][1]],[@board[1][1] + @board[4][2] + @board[7][1]], [@board[2][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[8][1]], [@board[3][2] + @board[6][2] + @board[9][1]], [@board[1][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[9][1]], [@board[3][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[7][1]]]
```

### Edit:

Ok, `*` applied only to the first array, my bad. 
This is a correct version.
You can see where I've put `()` instead of `[]`; By this I made array of strings.

Additionally you had you have checked wrong position on following combinations.

```
 @win_combo = [
                (@board[1][1] + @board[2][1] + @board[3][2]), # ok
                (@board[4][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[6][2]), # ok
                (@board[7][2] + @board[8][1] + @board[9][1]), # this # [7][2] not [7][1]
                (@board[1][1] + @board[4][2] + @board[7][2]), # this # [4][2] not [4][1]; [7][2]
                (@board[2][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[8][1]), # ok
                (@board[3][2] + @board[6][2] + @board[9][1]), # ok
                (@board[1][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[9][1]), # ok
                (@board[3][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[7][2])  # this [7][2] not [7][1]
               ]

       puts "\n#@win_combo\n"
       @win_combo
  end
```

ps. `puts "\n#@win_combo\n"` is for debuging your application. Delete it in release version.

Comment: Also, `win_combo` (the method) is never actually called, so the array is `nil`.

Comment: I made the changes but the loop won't break (I updated the code)